# Why is certificate permission not getting applied to signed stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I have a rather long stored procedure that I am using to generate a dataset for an SSRS report.  While I can run the report in Visual Studio using SSDT and deploy it (SQL SErver 2012), running it via report manager isn't working. It's having a problem with the dataset using the stored procedure.  If I try running the stored procedure using that login, I get:
 'Msg 1088, Level 16, State 7, Procedure *sp name*, Line 237
Cannot find the object "*table name*" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.'
  In both cases, I'm running against our development database.  The reporting services is NOT on the same machine as the data, and the SQL Server is not set up to work with Kerberos, so I'm running each report using credentials stored in SSRS.

1. All objects use the dbo schema owned by sa
2. the ssrs stored credential we use for reports is listed in SQL Server as having execute rights on the stored procedure (with no denys)-- we tend to not use roles.
3. Since the end of the stored procedure uses a dynamic query (I'm using pivot and the columns can change if new data items are added, hence use of dynamic query), I thought the ownership chain may have been broken.  Therefore, I tried creating a certificate (rather than use execute as), associating it with a sql  user & granting the user select rights on the above table, and signed the stored procedure with the certificate.
4. I checked the permissions on the cert user & it has select rights on the table.  My understanding is that the permissions granted to the cert user will be added to the permissions of the user running the stored procedure.  Yet I'm still getting the above error. I'm not sure why this isn't working...

The signature does show up & I have been re-signing whenever I change the stored proc.  I get error if I try running the dynamic sql as the certificate user.  As the user does exist and I am sysadmin, I guess that it cannot be impersonated Error is: Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "Cert_Dynamic_User" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission.

Comment: On its face, everything looks correct to me. A couple of things I'd check. 1) Does the signature show up in sys.crypt_properties? Altering the proc after signing deletes the signature, so this will just confirm that it's there. 2) Can you (manually, through SSMS frex) run the dynamic sql as the certificate user?

Comment: The problem was due to queries crossing databases.  I saved the certificate to file (I first signed the sp and removed the private key).  I then copied it to master & created login for.  Then copied it to the databases involved, created users based on login and gave each user appropriate permissions.  I also wrote up a script to handle, since whenever the sp changes, I will have to re-create the certificate.  I did this way based on information found here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21439/sharing-certificates-encryped-by-password-between-dbs-and-instances.  Any further comments?

Comment: Looks good except that you don't have to re-create the certificate every time the proc changes, you only need to re-issue the `add signature` statement using the existing certificate.